# Creating a for loop with find -exec and while

Tags: shell-script, find, date, ffmpeg

I am trying to make this script that loops through video files created between hours 00 and 12, convert them with ffmpeg and then remove them.

The script works in terms of finding the files and starting ffpmeg but it seems that it continues to "send" characters from the find -exec after that ffmpeg has started on the first conversion and it eventually breaks ffmpeg and stop the conversion. How can I modify the script so this does not happen?

The current script

```
!/bin/bash -e
find /videos/. -type f -print0 -exec sh -c 'h=$(date -d @$(stat -c %Y "$1") +%-H); [ "$h" -ge 00 ] && [ "$h" -lt 12 ]'   sh {} \;|while read -d $'\0' i;
do 
    ffmpeg -y -i "$i" -vcodec libx264 -crf 27 -preset veryfast -movflags +faststart -c:a copy -threads 14 /output/"$(basename "$i" .ts)".mp4
    rm -f -- "$i"
done
```

Comment: If you're trying to use the exit status of the `sh -c '...'` tests to filter the `find` results, shouldn't it go *before* the `-print0`?

Comment: See [Stackoverflow: "When reading a file line by line, I only get to execute ffmpeg on the first line"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36584391/when-reading-a-file-line-by-line-i-only-get-to-execute-ffmpeg-on-the-first-line) and [BashFAQ #89: "I'm reading a file line by line and running ssh or ffmpeg, only the first line gets processed!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089)

Comment: I tried moving -print0 to after `sh -c '...'`but I get "stat: cannot stat 'sh': No such file or directory" errors or no output or the same result depending on where I put it.

Comment: `... -type f -exec sh -c 'h=$(date -d @$(stat -c %Y "$1") +%-H); [ "$h" -ge 13 ] && [ "$h" -lt 23 ]' sh {} \;  -print | while read i;
do 
    ls -l "$i"`works fine but when I use $i as input file for ffmpeg it goes haywire.

Comment: I am testing now with adding  </dev/null at the end of the ffmpeg command. So far so good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Gordon Davisson I managed to solve the problem. Here is the complete working script if someone happens to stumple upon this issue in the future.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
find /videos/. -type f -exec sh -c 'h=$(date -d @$(stat -c %Y "$1") +%-H); [ "$h" -ge 00 ] && [ "$h" -lt 12 ]' sh {} \; -print | while IFS= read -r i;
do 
    ffmpeg -y -i "$i" -vcodec libx264 -crf 27 -preset veryfast -movflags +faststart -c:a copy -threads 14 /output/"$(basename "$i" .ts)".mp4 </dev/null
    rm -f -- "$i"
done
```

Comment: A couple more recommendations occur to me: I'd move the time check into the while loop, so you're only using a single shell -- that is, have `find` list *all* files, then check the date in the loop & only run `ffmpeg` if it's in the right range. Also, it'd be best to make the `rm` conditional on `ffmpeg` succeeding. So it should be something like `while ... do h=$(...); [ "$h" -ge 00 ] && [ "$h" -lt 12 ] && ffmpeg ... && rm ...; done

Comment: I agree with your comment Gordon. I have another issue with files modified during hour 23. For example files modified 23:45 will not be included in the list. How can I solve this?

Comment: I solved it by using the '-le' operator listed here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: Helpful. Thanks!