# Convert .ts videos to .mp4 with find piped into while and ffmpeg?

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a bunch of video `.ts` files to `.mp4`, but the way I think I have to go, is that while finding the files with `find` pipe the results into a `while` loop, execute `ffmpeg` on each file and then remove the old `.ts` file that was converted.
This is what I get with find:

```
$ find ./ -iname "*.ts"
./Parent-Dir/video1.ts
./Parent-Dir/video2.ts
./Parent-Dir/video3.ts
./Parent-Dir/video4.ts
..
..
.. about a 100 more videos ..
```

Can I do this with `find` and a `while` loop, something like this?

```
find ./ -iname "*.ts" | while IFS= read video
do
  ffmpeg -i "${video}" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac "${video}".mp4 
  rm -f ${video}.ts
done
```

Comment: Yes, you can. But your script need tome corrections. For example you will end with filenames like `video1.ts.mp4`

Comment: That's right. That's where I need help at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, this was what worked perfectly for me:

```
find ./ -iname "*.ts" \
  | while IFS= read -r video; do
    ffmpeg -nostdin -i "${video}" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac "${video%.*}".mp4
    rm -f "${video}"
  done
```

From `video.ts` it will convert it to `video.mp4`. Exactly what I was looking for!
Inspired from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505679/creating-a-for-loop-with-find-exec-and-while).
Thank you for the help @Romeo Ninov!

Answer (score 1):

To have correct filename you should change

```
ffmpeg -i "${video}" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac "${video}".mp4
```

to

```
ffmpeg -i "${video}" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac "${video%.*}".mp4
```

Also will be better to use `for` like:

```
for video in **/*.ts
```

This will not catch `.TS` but will handle better searching

And always add quoting when remove file:

```
rm -f "${video}"
```

Comment: `for` doesn't really work for me!

Comment: @techsk8, just idea